# bloc handleError does not catch error in dart

Tags: unit-testing, flutter, dart, stream

So I am using the flutter_bloc plugin and I want to throw an exception for invalid states.

```
@injectable
class MyBloc extends Bloc<MyEvents, MyStates> {
   MyBloc();

   @override
   MyStates get initialState => MyStates.initial();

   @override
   Stream<MyStates> mapEventToState(MyEvents event) async* {
      throw Exception();
   }
}
```

then I want to unit test whether the exception was thrown. I always get an unhandled error exception despite me using the handleError wrapper and the anything matcher. How to I catch this error?

```
expectLater(bloc.handleError((err, _) => print(err)), emits(anything));
```

The error message is

```
Unhandled error Exception occurred in bloc Instance of 'MyBloc'.
```

Comment: please show full bloc contents

Comment: @SergeySalnikov it's literally the default code from the plugin. I added it

Answer (score 0):

From Felix Angelov's answer here: https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/815

> you can just let the exception bubble up by not wrapping the code in a
> try/catch and then you can use blocTest with errors to verify an error
> occurred.
>
> ```
> blocTest(
>   'CounterBloc throws Exception when null is added',
>   build: () async => CounterBloc(),
>   act: (bloc) => bloc.add(null),
>   errors: [
>     isA<Exception>(),
>   ]
> );
> ```
>
> Hope that helps

Thank you so much :) it is exactly what I was looking for :)